# Can't change with android XML file

Tags: android, xml, view

I want to build an XML file like this:

[image]

But I can't. Can someone tell me why this happens? How to made center of edit box hint?

Specially edit box

[image]

**Here's my code:**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Button1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:background="#013567" />

                <LinearLayout
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                    android:weightSum="1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                    <!--  Email Label -->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:text="Large Text"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:textColor="#fe9900"
                        android:layout_weight="0.07"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <EditText android:layout_width="268dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:hint="Enter Email Address" />
                    <!--  Password Label -->
                    <EditText android:layout_width="274dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:password="true"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:hint="Password" />
                    <!-- Login button -->
                    <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                        android:text="Login"
                        android:background="#fe9900"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

                    <!-- Link to Registration Screen -->

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="31dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Medium Text"
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="34dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#013469" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I see several problems here. **1** - `fill_parent` has been deprecated 6 years ago. Use `match_parent`, instead. **2** - You use a lot of nested layouts, which you really don't need and have an **impact on performances**. A single RelativeLayout, if correctly used, is all you need. And will perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in the edittext xml you want to center and remove                     `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` from the email textview. You should also remove `android:password="true"` as is deprecated. Just a little tip, when a line of xml-code is yellow. There is something that may or maybe a problem with it. Hover it and see a message and click the lightbuld at the left side for more options. Something like this below should work.

```
<!--  Email Label -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
                android:textColor="#fe9900"
                android:layout_weight="0.07"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

            <EditText android:layout_width="268dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:hint="Enter Email Address" />
            <!--  Password Label -->
            <EditText android:layout_width="274dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:password="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:hint="Password" />
```